# AJAX unable to define the key's method in Django

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

First off, sorry for the odd phrasing of the title.

I currently have a webapp that allows users to order food from a resturant. In the menu html I currently have the following snippet.

```
{% if latest_order %}
<table class="table" id="checkout-table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col">YOUR</th>
      <th scope="col">CART</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  {% for order in latest_order %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ order.order_name }}</td>
    <td class="change-quantity">
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="submit" name="remove_quantity" value="{{ order.id }}"
            class="mr-3 btn btn-outline-info">-</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            {{ order.order_quantity }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="submit" name="add_quantity" value="{{ order.id }}" class="ml-3 btn 
            btn-outline-info">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>${{ order.order_individual_price }}</td>
```

in my JS I have the following AJAX code running

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ramen").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        var serializedData = $("#ramen-form").serialize()

        $.ajax({
            url: $("ramen-form").data("url"),
            data: serializedData,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#checkout-table").append('<tr><td>' + response.new_order.order_name + '</td><td class="change-quantity">' +
                                            '<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}<div class="row"><div class="col-sm">' +
                                            '<button type="submit" name="remove_quantity" value="{{ order.id }}"class="mr-3 btn btn-outline-info">-</button>' +
                                            '</div><div class="col-sm">'+ response.new_order.order_quantity +'</div><div class="col-sm">' +
                                            '<button type="submit" name="add_quantity" value="{{ order.id }}" class="ml-3 btn btn-outline-info">+</button>' +
                                            '</div></div></form></td><td>$'+ response.new_order.order_individual_price +'</td><form method="post">{% csrf_token %}<th>' +
                                            '<button type="submit" name="delete" value="{{ order.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Item</button></th></form></tr>')
            }
        })
    });
})
```

In my views.py I have the following to return a JsonResponse

```
         get_price = menu_name.Menu_price
         get_desc = menu_name.Menu_Desc
         new_order = Order.objects.create(
            customer=request.user, 
            order_name=menu_name, 
            order_individual_price=get_price, 
            order_default_price=get_price,
            order_desc = get_desc,
            )
          return JsonResponse({'new_order':model_to_dict(new_order)}, status=200)
```

AJAX returns the following error after I try to add an item to cart

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you don't parse the response. So, JQuery doesn't read it becase it is a string, not JSON. You might add the following to your AJAX call to parse it automatically:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Since you're using JQuery, you might also use `$.parseJSON()` to parse `response`.